# '=' expected got RH

Tags: lua

i have been Programming Lua with the game Roblox!
but my code i'm trying to build does not work!

```
RH = Instance.new("Motor6D", T)
RH.DesiredAngle = -0.044
RH.MaxVelocity = 0.15
RH.Name = "Right Hip"
RH.Part0 = Torso
RH.Part1 = Right Leg

RS = Instance.new("Motor6D", T)
RS.DesiredAngle = 0.044
RS.MaxVelocity = 0.15
RS.Name = "Right Shoulder"
RS.Part0 = Torso
RS.Part1 = Right Arm
```

it says expected '=' got RH

Can anyone please tell me why
Also my theory is that

```
RH.Part1 = Right Leg
```

is causing the problem.
When i put it in quotes it says

```
RH.Part1 = "Right Leg" Object Needed not string
```

(something along those lines)
So can anybody tell me how to weld with two words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. Lua is complaining about `RH.Part1 = Right Leg`, which it sees as `RH.Part1 = Right` followed by `Leg RS = Instance.new("Motor6D", T)`, and this is a syntax error.

The fix `RH.Part1 = "Right Leg"` does work at compile time but not at run time because of the semantics of Roblox. From what I could gather on line, `RH.Part1` needs to be an object. And so does `RH.Part0`. Since `Torso` is not defined in that code, you get `nil`.

Bottom line: you need to define objects named `Torso`, `Right_Leg`, `Right_Arm` before you used them.

Comment: i defined Torso as T and Right Leg as RL and Right Arm as RA

Comment: And when i defined t.name it says its a string with all of them

Comment: Nvm those too comments, i was stupid all i had to to was Define model then define those

Comment: Sorry! i hope that did not bother you